Getting start date of year
Can anyone help me with little problem? I am trying to get first month of given year.
    func createEmptyYearChartData(year: Date, month: Int = 1, chartEntries: [ChartModel]) -> [ChartModel] {
        var chartData = chartEntries
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: year)
        let currentMonth = month
        
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.year = currentYear
        components.month = month
        
        let date = calendar.date(from: components)
        guard let date = calendar.date(from: components) else { return [] }
        
            if month >= 12 {
                components.month = 12
                chartData.append(ChartModel(date: calendar.date(from: components)!, count: 0))
                return chartData
            } else {
                if currentMonth == month{
                    chartData.append(ChartModel(date: date, count: 0))
                    chartData = createEmptyYearChartData(year: date, month: month + 1, chartEntries: chartData)
                }
                return chartData
            }
    }

This is the function I use to populate data by recursion, when the function fires I get the result of first date from past years 31. December. The year passed in parameter is simply Date() object.
Edit per clarification request.
    func aggregateYearlyTransactions(from transactions: [ExpenseEntry], forYear date: Date) {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        
        let objects = createEmptyYearChartData(year: date, chartEntries: [])
        print(objects)
    }

Right now this is my function call, I expect return objects with date values from January to December.
But the output right now is following:
[
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 31BC8706-CF32-412E-AD17-156688EF5E30, date: 2023-12-31 22:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 5D7379A1-E509-4B75-AF2F-6F4206F36977, date: 2024-01-31 22:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 02571E50-5FFF-4C13-987F-D2F3C7A8849A, date: 2024-02-29 22:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 7FE5CBCD-65B3-4368-8EAB-27B0018D9DCF, date: 2024-03-31 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: B2F5D804-FBAB-460A-9FE1-C2037701F49A, date: 2024-04-30 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 6D9BE539-EA9A-427F-BCAB-AE600DFB1792, date: 2024-05-31 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 00F6F464-186C-4400-BD7E-38F1659F9124, date: 2024-06-30 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 93E623E2-8A11-4F2D-92FE-D2CE5F48B586, date: 2024-07-31 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 743A30A4-3CD3-42EC-8020-A91008F433AF, date: 2024-08-31 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 34D67AA6-D941-4C33-AB83-6A3D8AB052A6, date: 2024-09-30 21:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 6721E21C-BFD2-469D-8DD9-E7004C9E0373, date: 2024-10-31 22:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false), 
ExpenseX.ChartModel(id: 32E7DC9F-BB03-44F3-A32F-54F600BE6ED4, date: 2024-11-30 22:00:00 +0000, count: 0.0, animate: false)
]

Notice the first printed object, it is December 31 of 2023 and the last date is November not December.
Edit 2:
I have updated the function by adding the 1 day to date after getting it from components.
    func createEmptyYearChartData(year: Date, month: Int = 1, chartEntries: [ChartModel]) -> [ChartModel] {
        var chartData = chartEntries
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: year)
        
        var components = DateComponents()
        components.year = currentYear
        components.month = month
        
        let date = calendar.date(from: components)
        guard let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date!) else { return [] }
        
        if month >= 12 {
            chartData.append(ChartModel(date: startDate, count: 0))
            return chartData
        } else {
            chartData.append(ChartModel(date: startDate, count: 0))
            return createEmptyYearChartData(year: year, month: month + 1, chartEntries: chartData)
        }
    }

Is this valid for the long haul by adding one day to every year to get the correct date?

Please show an example of how you are calling this function. Also show the output you get, and the output you expected.

@Sweeper I have added an additional edit to clarify the question.

The dates are correct. Consider that print shows Date objects  in UTC. Your time zone is apparently UTC+0200 (daylight saving time UTC+0300).

Not clear to me what you want to achieve. "First month"  of any year of any calendar is always 1 - which is an Integer number. Current month of the current date: let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()).

When dealing with a Calendar, especially Calendar.current, you should not make the assumption that this is the Gregorian calendar which has 12 month. Calendar has functions to determine the valid range of any component for this type of calendar: maximumRange(of:).

Actually, it's an expected result. You were passing Date() to calculate the range from the first day of the current year to the first day of the last month in this year. i,e 01/01/2024 - 12/01/2024 (MM/dd/yyyy).
Date() itself is UTC date time when print out, it depends on your local time:
print(Date())

//2024-05-07 07:56:11 +0000

//2024-05-07 14:56:11 at my time zone (GMT+7)

Then, you didn't set hour/minute/second with in your DateComponents, and DateComponents uses a 24-hour format. Therefore, it will take your current time zone as the default time, which I am assuming is GMT+2. That's why you saw 22:00:00 +0000
You can try to print out the date value with DateFormatter.localizedString:
for model in models {
    let date = DateFormatter.localizedString(
        from: model.date,
        dateStyle: .long,
        timeStyle: .long)
    print(date)
}

1 January 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 February 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 March 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 April 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 May 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 June 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 July 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 August 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 September 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 October 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 November 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7
1 December 2024 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+7


Yeah, sorry for the mistake, I mean it's when print().

@CouchDeveloper Thank you for the answer, but small thing I wan to understand, would the correct way be to set the January 1 to time 00:00:00 and December 31 to 23:59:59 or just deal with time zones?

IMOP, if your app will support several nations, then you should expect the time zone. Otherwise, you can ignore it and use DateFormatter with certain formats.

Thank you for clarification, this helped a lot and led me to fixing the issue.

@lvars A Date() is just an (abstract) value representing a point in time - without any dependencies of a calendar. The system internally represents a date value with a Double - and relates this to a well known internal reference date. That is, the current point in time is the sum of the date value  and the internal reference value. Printing an abstract date can be formatted with UTC, where you get "2024-05-07 08:28:46Z" as an example. Here, no calendar is present - it's "zulu" time. In order to print it as local time, you need the current locale - which determines format and offset.

@CouchDeveloper yeah I added to Calendar.current the calendar.timezone = .current and it fixed the issue and understood this little fraction from dates.
